# How to execute a where clause in this scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach

**dbo.Images - Table**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN98b.jpg

**Image.cs**

```
 public class Image
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string ImagePath { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }
        public class ImageDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**ImageController.cs**

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    private ImageDBContext db = new ImageDBContext();

       public ActionResult Index(int ImageID)
    {
        return View(db.Images.Where(img => img.ID == ImageID).ToList());
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
 @model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Image>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }

   <img src="~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor(ImagePath.Where(ImageID == 2))" />
```

With reference to the code above I'm trying to display `ImagePath` from the table by selecting the related `ID`. Having `@Html.DisplayFor` retrieving and viewing the image from the `'ImagePath'` `Where` `ID` is valued 2 or 3 or 4. With this working successfully I would be able to input any url stored image from database onto an `<img src=""/>` on `.cshtml` individually. The below code isn't displaying the image with `ID` valued 2.

```
 <img src="~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor(ImagePath.Where(ImageID == 2))" />
```

**Any ideas?**

Highly appreciate your help and time.

Comment: If you are going to run a `where` query then you don't need the foreach loop i think. Your question isn't very clear...

Comment: You are already limiting what is returned by the controller to only a specific ID and only this image can be displayed.

Comment: There's no specific ID written in the controller.

Comment: You controller clearly says `Images.Where(img => img.ID == ImageId).ToList()` this piece of code is a query to get a SPECIFIC image/ID.

Comment: I've updated my answer .. check the end part .. it shows how to write the controller so it returns all the images and not just the one passed in the ImageID parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting it wrong i think.

`@Html.DisplayFor` should provide html code to display the model/property you pass it.

What you need is this below.

```
<img src="~/Images/@(Model.First(x=> x.ID == 2).ImagePath)" />
```

This will throw an error if no item is returned.

You are already limiting what is returned by the controller to only a specific ID and only this image can be displayed.

Be sure that the ID passed to the Controller is also 2

Alternatively you can simply use whatever image is returned ... see below.

```
<img src="~/Images/@(Model.First().ImagePath)" />
```

If you want the contoller to return all the images, see below.

```
   public ActionResult Index(int ImageID)
    {
        return View(db.Images.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: ..but how can I display a specific image from the table? if for example I want the image with ID == 3 and image with ID ==4 without changing anything in the controller... in order to select the ID from the <img src ="">.

Comment: The controller is where the list of images is supposed to come from .. so if you already limit it to one there, you can't get it on the cshtml page. if you want to be able to select it then you have to remove the where clause from the controller. I'll update my answer

Comment: Next step do the exact same thing in javascript haha... any clue?

Comment: What aspect do you want to do in javascript?